# C++ design for encoder/decoder classes with different stored types

Tags: design-patterns, c++, inheritance

I need to handle different elements in a vector, each element owning a specific parameter (integer or string), so that I can easily handle encoding/decoding of a series of elements.

- Encoding a list of elements serializes the elements, inserting a separator in-between each.
- Decoding a string consists in finding the separators then for each substring, extracting the ID and type-specific value. Example (knowing that "FOO" is associated to an integer and "BAR" is associated to a string): "FOO=54,BAR=hello" gives {{ID_FOO, 54}, {ID_BAR, "hello"}} .

I have the current following bare design:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

enum eID { /*...*/ };

// Base class
class Base {
private:
    enum eID m_Id;
public:
    Base(enum eID = 0): m_Id(eID) {}
    virtual std::string Encode() {
        // Return encoding of m_Id
    }
    static Base* Decode(const std::string &str) {
        Base *ptr;
        // Extract id
        // According to the kind of id, create a new Derived<T>
        // giving the substring to the constructor
        // ptr = new Derived<...>(id, str.substr(...));
        return ptr;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Derived<T> : public Base {
private:
    T m_Value;
public:
    Derived(enum eID id, const std::string &str); // participates to decoding
    std::string Encode();
};

template<>
Derived<std::string>::Derived(enum eID id, const std::string &str) {
    m_Value = str; // easy
}

template<>
std::string Derived<std::string>::Encode() {
    return static_cast<Base*>(this)->Encode() + m_Value;
}

template<>
Derived<long>::Derived(enum eID id, const std::string &str) {
    m_Value = strtol(str.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
}

template<>
std::string Derived<long>::Encode() {
    // Encode id and integer param to a string
}

class BaseList {
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> m_List;
public:
    void Append(Base *ptr) {
        m_List.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(ptr));
    }
    std::string Encode() {
        // Call each Encode() function and concatenate strings together
        // Insert a delimiter in-between substrings
    }
    void Decode(const std::string &sToDecode) {
        // Look for delimiters in sToDecode
        // For each delimited substring:
        // - call Base::Decode() to allocate a new type-specific object
        // - push back into m_List
    }
}
```

(This is not be a complete compiling example.)

Is it a logic design? How could it be optimized so that it may match any existing design pattern(s)? In particular I am concerned with the decoding technique, which here is split into BaseList::Decode() and the static method Base::Decode().

Comment: If there's no hard requirement on the specific serialized format I think I'd start with [boost::serialize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)

Comment: Actually the "serialized" format is part of a predefined communication protocol, so that cannot be customized; but internal representation of data (id and type-specific value of each element whose order must be kept in vector) can be upgraded.

Comment: You need a factory (pattern) for decoding elements.

Comment: As far as I understand, my Base::Decode() static function appears as factory pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the actual question was about how to handle the difference between {FOO, 54} and {BAR, "hello"}. This is classic use case of an union:

```
struct A { int id; union { long val; std::string s; } un; };
```

unfortunately, unions don't handle constructors very well, so std::string wont work very well inside union (unless they changed it recently :-). But there's another way to implement an union:

```
class Union {
public:
  Union() : m_s(0), m_val(0) {}
  Union(std::string s) : m_s(new string(s)), m_val(0) { }
  Union(long val) : m_s(0), m_val(new long(val)) { }
  ~Union() { delete m_s; delete m_val; }
  Union(const Union &u) 
  : m_s(u.m_s ? new string(*u.m_s) : 0), 
    m_val(u.m_val ? new long(*u.m_val) : 0) { }
  void operator=(const Union &u) { 
        delete m_s; m_s=0;
        delete m_val; m_val=0;
        if (u.m_s) m_s = new std::string(*u.m_s); 
        if (u.m_val) m_val = new long(*u.m_val);
        }
 private:
  std::string *m_s; 
  long *m_val;
 };
```

NULL pointers are indicating that the value is not being used. (note that this Union class becomes a nightmare to maintain, if you need to add more alternative types to it)

Now the required struct looks like this:

```
struct A { int id; Union u; };
```

Once you have this, making an array out of it is very trivial:

```
std::vector<A> vec;
```

will be able to store values like {{ID_FOO,33}, {ID_BAR,"hello"}}

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up when writing serialization was the following:

```
class ParserPairBase 
{
public:
//virtual std::type_info TypeInfo() const=0;
virtual size_t SizeOf() const=0;
struct PtrSize
{
  char *ptr;
  size_t size;
};
virtual PtrSize BaseParse(std::string s, bool &success) const=0;
virtual std::string BaseCreate(PtrSize psz) const=0;
};

template<class T>
class ParserPair : public ParserPairBase 
{
public:
   virtual std::string Create(T t) const=0;
   virtual T Parse(std::string s, bool &success) const=0;
   //std::type_info TypeInfo() const { return typeid(T); }
   virtual size_t SizeOf() const { return sizeof(T); }
   virtual PtrSize BaseParse(std::string s, bool &success) const
      {
      PtrSize sz;
      T *ptr = new T;
      sz.ptr = (char*)ptr;
      sz.size = sizeof(T);
      *ptr = Parse(s, success);
      return sz;
      }
    virtual std::string BaseCreate(PtrSize psz) const
       {
       T *ptr = (T*)psz.ptr;
       std::string s = Create(*ptr);
       return s;
       }
   };
```

And then just derived classes will implement Create() and Parse():

```
class CharParser : public ParserPair<char>
{
public: 
   std::string Create(char c) const { std::string s; s+=c; return s; }
   char Parse(std::string s, bool &success) const { 
      if (s.length()!=1) { success = false; return ' '; } 
      success = true; 
      return s[0]; 
   }
};
```

Unfortunately, this is getting too long for the site, but using these base classes, it's possible to create for example a parser for arbitrary structs. See this link for further details: http://sourceforge.net/p/gameapi/code/ci/master/tree/GameApi/Parser.hh

I'll create another answer for answering your actual question.